# get Skype chat history from .dbb files into new main.db

Tags: mac

Hi quick question we have an old skype user that updated from a very old mac version of skype to 7.44 and now all old skype chat history is gone .

When we look at the files we can see the new Main.DB and also the chatmsg256.dbb files .. so from what I have seen and read it looks like Skype moved away from chatmsg256.dbb to main.db in one of the version updates ..

Is there a way to merge or add the data from the chatmsg256.dbb into the new main.db ?

thanks